# How to use functions from different file in sublime 3 Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

For example if I have a folder for my project and 2 files inside it, how do I use data from one file in the other?

Example:
File1.JS

```
var objectFromFile1={name:obj1};
```

File2.JS
How do I use the objectFromFile in this file?
How do I do `objectFromFile1.name` in File 2?

This is sublime 3 and JS
Thanks

Comment: How does this relate to Sublime? It is a text editor. It supports plugins, but it expects them to be written in Python. Presumably you are using it as an editor for JS that you plan to run some other way. What way is that? Are you using Node.JS? Windows Scripting Host? Are you writing an HTML document that they run inside? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you reference both of those files in an html file and load the html file in the browser, objectFromFile1 will be on the global scope so file 2 will be able to see it. If you'd like to provide an abstraction layer over your files that helps you break your files into modules that can be used by other modules, check out requirejs http://requirejs.org/ or some similar library.

Comment: It most certainly can, and will. The request for the file may happen in a synchronous order, but the file is not guaranteed to load in any particular order.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you consider to be incorrect. what would you like the edit to be?

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: Sublime Text doesn't recognize names of two files at once.

@Patrick replied correctly. But if you don't have access to the HTML page, then you can use the `XMLHttpRequest` constructor to load your `File1.js` and execute its content with the `Function` constructor, and in this case, `objectFromFile1` should be defined in `window` object to be global in your script, e.g `window.objectFromFile1 = {};`.

```
// Construct the XHR object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

// Configure the XHR
xhr.get("GET", "File1.js", true);

// When the XHR change its ready state
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
        if(this.status === 200) {
            /* Success */
            (new Function(this.responseText))();
            /* Your callback goes here */
            /* Example: */
            alert(objectFromFile1.name);
        }else{
            /* Error loading the file */
        }
    }
};

// Do the request
xhr.send();
```